# Can't install or buy apps from App Store on iPad mini iOS 7

Tags: itunes, ipad, ios-appstore, ios

I’m trying to buy apps or music from App Store and iTunes but isn't working. Every time I try I get the "Purchase Could Not Be Completed" message (see screenshot below).

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you get it fixed... I'm going through the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the message itself, you may have to contact iTunes Support.

Things you can try yourself first

- log out of the App Store in Settings and log in again (then retry the purchase)
- restart your iPad
- log in to the Store via iTunes on Mac/PC and try to purchase the app there.
- log in to the Store via iTunes and verify your paymend details (maybe your credit card got rejected)